# Symfony 2 Mac Apache and Prod environment

Tags: php, macos, apache, symfony

I am unable to get Symfony 2.x running in the prod environment on my MacBook.

`localhost/app_dev.php` runs fine and `check.php` etc but not prod.

I have tried all the usual fixes, such as `chmod -R 777`, `775` etc on my `/Users/user/Sites` folder.
I have chown the folder to `_www:_www` recursively as well.
I have also tried adding `FollowSymLinks` and `Allowoverride` to VHOSTs and my user conf in Apache. but still no luck.

The "error" I get is....

> The connection was reset
>
> The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

Nothing more, nothing less. No errors in the log files (symfony prod & apache), nothing.

Like I said though… dev environment works fine. On my Windows and Linux machines both environments work perfectly, only problems on the Mac.

**UPDATE:**
With a bit of debugging, I found that app.php is being called, but it seems to "crash" at the following line

```
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
```

Comment: "No errors in the log files, nothing" : which log files ? Symfony prod.log or Apache error.log ?

Comment: yes, symfony and apache logs remain empty

Comment: are you using the macport version of PHP ? Or MAMP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Symfony is a PHP framework correct?  My first suggestion is to not deal with the built in Mac OS X Apache/PHP setup & instead use [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/). It’s a self contained Mac version of a LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL & PHP) environment.  And it is far more on par with the real world of web development than Apple’s built-in tools go.

That said, to diagnose your current setup, I think you should check headers from the requests you are making to see what is truly happening.  You would do this using `curl -I` like this:

```
curl -I localhost/app_dev.php
```

Or like this:

```
curl -I localhost/check.php
```

Also, are you checking the Apache & PHP logs?  Might glean more clues from those.  As it stands, my best recommendation to get you back on track is to use [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/) instead of this type of setup.

Comment: thank for your reply. yes the apache and symfony log files remain empty. header for app_dev.php return correctly but app.php the prod environment return as empty reply from server.